# How can I position a view offscreen programmatically when it's parent is a ConstraintLayout? (Android)

Tags: android, view, android-constraintlayout

I would like to position a view "above" the screen so that I can later make it slide into the screen (downwards). The view is inside a ConstraintLayout - Nothing seems to be working and the view's height is "wrap_content".

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use Translate
put below code in your anim folder

```
<translate

    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
    android:startOffset="100"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

and then you can use it in

```
trans1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate1);
abc.setAnimation(trans1);
```

Comment: My question isn't about writing a translate animation. It's regarding positioning of a view